# Emulate Keystrokes with Python in Linux

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am writing a script in Python using Selenium that auto fills out a web form (a helpdesk ticketing system)

A factor in this is the body of the ticket does not have an element id that Selenium recognizes, so in order to type in the body I have to find the title element,  press the tab key, then start typing in to the body.

Here is some code that writes a message into the body:

```
der = "/t this is the desc"
driver.find_element_by_id("title").send_keys(der)
```

The problem is, this code doesnt work for me. What I really need to do would look like this:

```
body = open(email.txt)
driver.find_element_by_id("title").send_keys("/t" + body)
```

So I want it to find the title element, press the tab key, then write what is stored in the body variable into the body of the ticket. the only issue is that syntax is bad.

I looked at SendKeys but that is windows only. I am using Fedora 16.

Any help/recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: You mention that the body of the ticket does not have an element id that Selenium recognizes.  Are you able to use CSS locators to select it? Using driver.find_element_by_css_selector() or as a last resort using xpath driver.find_element_by_xpath().

Comment: i found the bindings doc (http://readthedocs.org/docs/selenium-python/en/latest/locating-elements.html) and saw the ways to find elements. I insatlled FireBug, and went through the page. I ended up finding a class_name that looked promising and it ended up working.

my code ended up driver.find_element_by_class_name("ze_area").send_keys("this is the body")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in your code. Change this:

```
body = open(email.txt)
```

to:

```
body = open("email.txt").read()
```

Comment: You are welcome. Accepting my answer would of course be appreciated! :-)

Comment: well, technically, my original code had this, the real issue was answered above by Isaac.

Comment: I actually missed that detail. Thanks anyway!